# Android in-app billing v3

Tags: android, google-play, payment, in-app-billing

Good Day!

I am implementing in-app billing v3 for my app. I followed all the steps from the android tutorial, but it says "Application is not found"

I uploaded the apk file onto Alpha version.
Created list of products.
I am in the testers list.
Package names are identical.

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bindService(new 
            Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
                    mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

And

```
    case R.id.ss_next:
        startService(new Intent(this, service_test.class).setFlags(3));

        break;
    case R.id.d_bok:
        stopService(new Intent(this, service_test.class));
        ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String> ();
        skuList.add("premiumUpgrade");
        skuList.add("gas");
        Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
        querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
        try {
            Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, "",
                    "25coins", "i", "b");

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
            startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
                       1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
                       Integer.valueOf(0));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you download app then this happen

Comment: @Pawanasati could you clarify this,please?

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%8093_A_Tutorial           i used this link and it is working properly with test account also

Comment: When it is uploade?? it will take an hour

Comment: @Pawanasati I followed the tutorial, It works with google test product, but not with mine

Comment: @Pawanasati Finally, I solved the problem, your tutorial link helped much! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You must set in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<!-- VERY IMPORTANT! Don't forget this permission, or in-app billing won't work. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```